# xml Error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, xml

My DOMParser is throwing this exception when reading the xml

```
[Fatal Error] .... The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

My XML is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PacketDetails>
       <RefrenceNumber>SLP264531195</RefrenceNumber>
       <AwbNumber>83047273</AwbNumber>
       <ShipperAccountNumber>Cus092</ShipperAccountNumber>
       <ConsigneeAddress>1.0,835210</ConsigneeAddress>
       <ConsigneePhone>1</ConsigneePhone>
       <StatusChanges>
              <Status>
                     <StatusId>1</StatusId>
                     <StatusName>Return to Origin - Delivered</StatusName>
                     <city>Delhi</city>
                     <UpdateDate>2015-04-04</UpdateDate>
                 </Status>
              <Status>
                     <StatusId>3</StatusId>
                     <StatusName>Return to Origin - Received</StatusName>
                     <city>Delhi</city>
                     <UpdateDate>2015-04-04</UpdateDate>
                 </Status>
              <Status>
                     <StatusId>1</StatusId>
                     <StatusName>Return to Origin - In transit</StatusName>
                     <city>Delhi</city>
                     <UpdateDate>2015-03-28</UpdateDate>
                 </Status>
              <Status>
                     <StatusId>1</StatusId>
                     <StatusName>Return to Origin - In transit</StatusName>
                     <city>Delhi</city>
                     <UpdateDate>2015-03-12</UpdateDate>
                 </Status>
              <Status>
                     <StatusId>2</StatusId>
                     <StatusName>Packet - out of delivery area</StatusName>
                     <city>Ranchi</city>
                     <UpdateDate>2015-03-10</UpdateDate>
                 </Status>
              <Status>
                     <StatusId>2</StatusId>
                     <StatusName>Packet - out of delivery area</StatusName>
                     <city>Ranchi</city>
                     <UpdateDate>2015-03-07</UpdateDate>
                 </Status>
              <Status>
                     <StatusId>4</StatusId>
                     <StatusName>Out for delivery</StatusName>
                     <city>Ranchi</city>
                     <UpdateDate>2015-03-07</UpdateDate>
                 </Status>
              <Status>
                     <StatusId>8</StatusId>
                     <StatusName>Packet Received At Operation Facility</StatusName>
                     <city>Ranchi</city>
                     <UpdateDate>2015-03-07</UpdateDate>
                 </Status>
              <Status>
                     <StatusName>In Transit</StatusName>
                     <city>Patna</city>
                     <UpdateDate>2015-03-07</UpdateDate>
                 </Status>
              <Status>
                     <StatusId>9</StatusId>
                     <StatusName>Packet Forwarded To Destination</StatusName>
                     <city>Jharkhand</city>
                     <UpdateDate>2015-03-03</UpdateDate>
                 </Status>
              <Status>
                     <StatusId>8</StatusId>
                     <StatusName>Packet Received At Operation Facility</StatusName>
                     <city>Gurgaon</city>
                     <UpdateDate>2015-03-02</UpdateDate>
                 </Status>
          </StatusChanges>
   </PacketDetails>
```

I saw the other Qs on the forum, but it seems to me that the xml looks good. Please point me in the right direction.

Edit : xml comes from a URL. I have pasted the complete xml now, but it looks ok to me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with xml.  Where does the xml come from, a file or a http request.  I would check to see if there additional unprintable characters that are not seen in the xml stream.

Answer (score 2):

The XML you've shown is fine.

The problem lies with the XML you've not shown.  The error message indicates that there's a second root element, which is not allowed in [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) XML.

---

*Update after more XML posted*

The new XML you've shown is also fine.

As Michael Kay mentioned in the comments, this is not the XML that the parser is seeing.  **You have to find the XML that the parser is actually seeing to solve your problem:**

- You might have a dirty buffer problem.  Make sure that buffer you're
  handing to the parser has been cleared prior to adding your XML.
- You might be passing a different filename than the one associated
  with the file you think is being parsed.
- An earlier stage in your pipeline might be changing the XML prior to
  the parsing in question.
- ...

Try to dump the XML being given to the parser **immediately prior to parsing** so that you can be sure you're looking at what the parser is reading.  It is also conceivable, although not common/likely with most parsers I've seen, that the parser has not been properly initialized or reset after a prior run.  Really, focus on finding what the parser is really seeing to hone in on your problem.

Comment: You've shown the XML that you think you are parsing, but not the XML that the parser thinks it is parsing.